# Active Navlink en React Router v6 con Params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio con React Router y me pasa que cuando paso la ruta por props el style del active navlink me funciona ok, pero cuando lo hago por parámetros no me funciona!alquien sabe que es lo que puede estar pasando? paso el codigo  primero de mi componente NavBar, luego de mi componente Mensaje, y finalmente de mi componente App.

```
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Navbar=()=>

<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Inicio</NavLink>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
   
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink  to="/mensaje1/Mensaje nº1/purple" className="nav-link" 
       style={
          ({ isActive }) => 
          ({background: isActive ?'#f0f0f0':'#7600dc'})
          }    >Mensaje 1</NavLink>
      </li> 

----------------------------------------------
import { useParams, } from 'react-router';
import './Mensaje.css';

function Mensaje(props){
   
    let {msj,fondo}= useParams() 
    
  
    return (
        <div className='Mensaje'>
            <div className='Jumbotron' style={{backgroundColor:fondo}}>
            <h3>{msj}</h3>
            <hr/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab fugit et iure harum quidem vero placeat, cum dolore aperiam vitae! Ipsa aperiam et numquam eaque maxime minus amet fugit libero.
             Perferendis quis placeat quasi alias error et non facere veniam repellendus, saepe expedita tenetur eos a rem ad. Asperiores quibusdam quas modi hic sequi pariatur repellendus, inventore quam voluptatibus quod.
             </p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
---------------------------------------------------------------
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <div className='container mt-3'>
          <div className='jumbotron'>
           
              <h3>Router</h3>
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar/>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/mensaje1/:msj/:fondo'  element={<Mensaje/>}/>
           </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

Alguna ayuda??
gracias de antemano!